# Javascript Error: Could not find matching close tag for <%

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

Having issue with a .ejs file.

The following code is this

```
    26|         </thead>
    27|         <tbody>
 >> 28|           <%- include('include/_show') %>
    29|         </tbody>
    30|       </table>
    31|     </form>

Could not find matching close tag for "<%".
```

The error is on line 28 but I am unsure exactly what the issue is.

Edit: I have tried `<%- include('include/_show'); %>` and `<% include('include/_show') %>` with the same results. Searching the docs gives very little insight. https://ejs.co/#docs

Comment: Try to add `;` after the include (so `<%- include('include/_show'); %>`  )

Comment: The question title didn't match the question text; which is it? The error isn't here; did you check the included file?

Comment: Tried adding ; and the error message doesn't change.